# Is there any way to find out when an album got added to Spotify with the web API?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, spotify, webapi

My usecase is to present the latest added album of an artist (regardless of releasedate).

I use the [https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/[artistId]/albums](https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/%5BartistId%5D/albums) to get the albums but I can't find any information about how the response is ordered. Is it random or actually sorted by the date the album got added to Spotify?

By furthering query [https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-album/[albumId]](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-album/%5BalbumId%5D) I can get additional info like release-date but no data about when the album got added to Spotify.

Is it simply not possible or is there some cleaver way like looking at the `albumID` etc. to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting an answer from spotify is seems it's currently not possible to get this information.

"At the moment we are only exposing the release date of the album itself, not the date of addition to the Spotify index. We will take this into account as a feature request."
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artists-albums/